# Is there a list of OTC stocks being added to the major exchanges?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, online-data-source

I have been looking for a way of finding out what over-the-counter stocks are being listed on reputable stock exchanges such as the NYSE.

Is there a website that keeps a list of those?

Answer (score 1):

Check your broker's IPO list. Adding a new stock to a stock exchange is called "Initial Public Offering" (IPO), and most brokers have a list of upcoming IPO's in which their clients can participate.

Comment: I was under the impression that IPO's were only for companies that did not trade OTC previously. The following link say that an IPO is not carried out: http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/08/otc-nyse-nasdaq.asp#axzz21T04eodp

Comment: IPO *is* curried out, unless the company has been publicly traded already (for example, its traded OTC because it was de-listed from NYSE due to certain failures). Facebook is a good example: it was traded OTC, but had never been traded publicly, so there has never been an IPO. The first issue of stocks offered publicly was offered through IPO.

Comment: Facebook didn't have an IPO? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_IPO

Comment: Yes, it did. That's why  I brought it up as an example. The IPO was when it was offered for public trading on NASDAQ, even though it has been traded OTC years before.

Comment: +1 - because OTC used to include NASDAQ, but now, the latter is a larger exchange, and OTC refers to pink sheets or small shocks not listed on the big exchanges. So your answer is fine, the question might require clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Reuters has a service you can subscribe to that will give you lots of Financial information that is not readily available in common feeds.  One of the things you can find is the listing/delist dates of stocks.  There are tools to build custom reports.  That would be a report you could write.  You can probably get the data for free through their rss feeds and on their website, but the custom reports is a paid feature.

FWIW re-listing(listings that have been delisted but return to a status that they can be listed again) is pretty rare.  And I can not think of too many(any actually) penny stocks that have grown to be listed on a major exchange.